# How to get the variables from an Array built by parsing a HTML file

Tags: php, arrays, variables, html-parsing

Hi I wanted help in a situation where I have a folder called 'slides' and I have multiple text / html files in it like: slide1.html slide2.html slide3.html and so on.....

The structure of these files is like this:

```
<h2>Title of the Slide</h2>
<p><a href="http://mydomain.com"><img src="icon.png" width="227" height="227" alt="icon" longdesc="http://longdescription" /></a></p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
```

3 properties Title, Image and the Description. **One in each line**.

**----------- UPDATE ---------------**

I tried as suggested by @MATT but I am getting a blank screen: Here is the script of the entire page for reference. I am working on a Joomla template.

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die();
gantry_import('core.gantryfeature');

class GantryFeatureTabs extends GantryFeature {
    var $_feature_name = 'tabs';
    function init() {
        global $gantry;

        if ($this->get('enabled')) {
            $gantry->addScript('tabs.js');
            $gantry->addInlineScript($this->_tabs());
        }
    }
    function render($position="") {
        ob_start();
        foreach(glob("/tabs/*.html") as $fileName) {
        $fname = basename( $fileName );
        $curArr = file($fname);
        $slides[$fname ]['title'] = $curArr[0];
        $slides[$fname ]['image-links'] = $curArr[1];
        $slides[$fname ]['description'] = $curArr[2];

        foreach($slides as $key => $value){

            ?>
              <ul id="tabs1" class="tabs">
                <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $demo_tabs_url.$curArr; ?>"><?php echo $value['title'] ?></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <ul id="contents1" class="tabs-content">
                  <li>
                  <?php echo $value['image-links'] ?>
                  <?php echo $value['description'] ?>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            <?php
            }}
            ?>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    function _tabs() {
        global $gantry;
        $js = "
            window.addEvent('load',function() {
                var tabset = new TabSet($$('#tabs1 li a'),$$('#contents1 li'),{
                    cookieName: 'demo-list'
                });
            });
        ";
        return $js;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it obliged that you have all these files as they are? Or would you maybe prefer a database?

Comment: This is a Joomla template so even if you suggest a database driven stuff it should be fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

class GantryFeatureTabs extends GantryFeature 
{
    $_feature_name = 'tabs';
    function init() {
        global $gantry;

        if ($this->get('enabled')) {
            $gantry->addScript('tabs.js');
            $gantry->addInlineScript($this->_tabs());
        }
    }
    function render($position="") {
        ob_start();
        foreach(glob("/tabs/*.html") as $fileName) {
        $fname = basename( $fileName );
        $curArr = file($fname);
        $slides[$fname ]['title'] = $curArr[0];
        $slides[$fname ]['image-links'] = $curArr[1];
        $slides[$fname ]['description'] = $curArr[2];
}

        foreach($slides as $key => $value)
        {        
            ?>
              <ul id="tabs1" class="tabs">
                <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $demo_tabs_url.$curArr; ?>"><?php echo $value['title'] ?></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <ul id="contents1" class="tabs-content">
                  <li>
                  <?php echo $value['image-links']; ?>
                  <?php echo $value['description']; ?>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            <?php
        }
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    function _tabs() {
        global $gantry;
        $js = "
            window.addEvent('load',function() {
                var tabset = new TabSet($$('#tabs1 li a'),$$('#contents1 li'),{
                    cookieName: 'demo-list'
                });
            });
        ";
        return $js;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I've assumed here that your first two code samples work as expected, and your problem is with the last sample, as you haven't stated exactly what error you're getting.  Please feel free to be more specific on your question if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried your approach but it did not work. I have edited the question and also included my entire page script as is where with your suggested answer. Kindly go through it and suggest what is wrong. I am getting a blank screen

Comment: @Madhavi You've added an extra curly brace - remove the } immediately below the second foreach.

Comment: @Matt I tried removing the brace but still no luck. The second closing brace was of the first `foreach` statement so I even tried removing both (open and close) from the second `foreach` also and tried it but still no luck.

Comment: @Madhavi - Your last two echos don't have semicolons at the end - these are needed.  I've posted updated code in my answer.

Comment: Also, sorry I can't actually try it because I don't have Joomla or Gantry installed - if this one doesn't work I won't be able to help further unfortunately because all I can do is point out why your PHP might not be valid.

Comment: @Matt that first var is a valid keyword it belongs to the Gantry Framework and it works fine. If I remove that my script will not work. After trying your suggestion....It says `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line...` and in that line I have `foreach($slides as $key => $value) { `

Comment: I added the error_reporting(E_ALL) which is why you're now getting errors showing, rather than a blank page.  It seems that now the PHP is valid, therefore I'm not able to help you any further as I don't have the required frameworks installed, sorry I couldn't help!  You're right, var is a valid keyword, that was my mistake, sorry.

Comment: Hmmm ok. Thanks anyways for the help.